# Webservice consuming SP WebService - Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, web-services, credentials

Our SharePoint site is not accessible from outside. So I am working on a WebService (not hosted in SP) that will consume SP WebService (ListData Wcf). It's a kind of wrapper.

Anonymous access are not allowed with ListData, and on my development machine, everything works just fine by using my own credential

```
list.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

I guess it won't work when deploying to the Integration machine. May I add account credentials in order to the webservice to consume SP WebService ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084487/is-it-possible-to-pass-network-credentials-to-a-web-service-from-silverlight-ui

If I understand your question you want to add a specific account's credentials then try something like this:

```
list.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
```